# how to view data on data node

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I'm using mysql cluster, and I was knew mysql cluster auto sharding data on data node (when I use engine= ndb )  and my question is how can I show  data on data node machine when my database was sharding

Answer (score 0):

You can view the data on each node through the MySQL Server attached to the cluster